# Reuse front headphone jack as microphone jack

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, audio-jack

I have a *Realtek ALC 882* internal audio device in my computer, which supplies three front jacks. The microphone jack is broken (can confirm this from Win7) and I want to use the headphone jack to serve as microphone jack. This is physically possible, as it works on Win7 with the correct Realtek driver installed.

Is it possible to achieve the same setup with Ubuntu? How can I do this?

System info:

Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid, Desktop, 32bit, Unity

```
$ lspci -v -nn -s 00:1b.0
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5LD2-VM Mainboard (Realtek ALC 882 codec) [1043:817f]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at cfdf8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use`hdajackretask` for that, which is part of the package `alsa-tools-gui`.
You can install it with `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but even after remapping the jack with your tool, the Unity audio settings does not show any input device. Do you have any suggestions why no device does appear there and how I can get Ubuntu to detect it?